# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

I am a neophyte. I  have started using python on Ubuntu. My version is Python3.4
I wrote the following code & got error:

```
>>> g=input("Enter number here: ")
Enter number here: 43
>>> g+7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>> a= input("Enter:")
Enter:43
>>> a +32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>> a+32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>>
```

Can anybdy please help?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

`input` will return a `str`, you have to convert it to `int` to do numeric operations with it

```
>>> g = int(input('enter a number:'))
enter a number: 5

>>> g + 7
12
```

**Before conversion**

```
>>> g = input('enter a number:')
enter a number: 5

>>> type(g)
<class 'str'>
```

**After conversion**

```
>>> g = int(input('enter a number:'))
enter a number: 5

>>> type(g)
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> int(g)+7
```

... and:

```
>>> int(a) + 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this...
In python 3.4, `input()` is convert to string. you can call `g` and the result is `'43'`..this string..
so convert to `integer`

```
>>> g=input("Enter number here: ")
Enter number here: 43
>>> g+7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>> 
>>> g
'43'
>>> int(g)+7
50
>>>
```